# Can we implement C4 garbage collection mechanism in our own JVM?Or we will have to use only AZUL JVM(Zing)

Tags: java

I just want to use C4 garbage collection mechanism as Azul is using.
To implement it,will I have to use AZUL JVM(Zing)?
Or we can implement,it in our own server.

How Can I achive it our own server.

Answer (score 2):

The C4 collector implementation is part of the Zing JVM. You can install and run Zing on most Linux/x86 servers (including on AWS, etc.). You then just change JAVA_HOME to point to the Zing JDK, and everything gets happier.